# Пытаюсь на вордпресе сделать меню

Tags: wordpress, html5

ХТМЛ:

```
             <div class="main_menu">
                    <a id="touch-menu" class="mobile-menu" href="#"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>Menu</a>

        <nav>
     <ul class="menu">
       <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'  => 'main_menu') ); ?>
         <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>HOME</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>ABOUT US</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#"><i class="icon-camera"></i>PRICING</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>CONTACT US</a></li>-->
```

Get Started

в function.php добавил

register_nav_menu("Mnu" , "main_menu");

В самом ворпресе также все сделал

http://hkar.ru/Lbuc

На сайте меню появилось но при нажатие на сыллку оно открывает директорию (http://wapic.loc/about-us/) но на станицу about-us не перекидивает в чем проблема?

Comment: другое фото http://hkar.ru/Lbud

Comment: проверьте содержимое .htaccess (https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) или перейдите в Настройки > Permalinks и сохраните.

Comment: http://hkar.ru/LbwO
 там вроде все гуд!

Comment: Поможет кто????